# ¿"Sigla" o "siglas"? ¿Es correcto decir “Según su sigla” o “sus siglas”?

Tags: gramática, plurales

Siempre me pareció más natural la primera forma, pero leo habitualmente la segunda. Hoy veo en un periódico que alguien tiene el mismo problema:

> El VPH (según **su sigla** en castellano que significa *virus del papiloma humano*), pero más conocido como *hachepevé* (por **sus siglas** en inglés HPV) es una familia de virus que [...]

¿Cuál es la forma correcta? ¿O son válidas las dos?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Entiendo que son válidas las dos.

El DRAE recoge:

> [**sigla**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XqwEQdl)
>   *Del lat. tardío sigla 'cifras, abreviaturas'.*
>
> 1. f. Abreviación gráfica formada por el conjunto de letras iniciales de una expresión compleja; p. ej., ONU por Organización de las Naciones Unidas, ovni por objeto volador no identificado, IPC por índice de precios al consumo.
>
> 2. f. Cada una de las letras de una sigla (‖ abreviación formada por letras iniciales). P. ej., O, N y U son siglas en ONU.
>
> 3. f. Cualquier signo que sirve para ahorrar letras o espacio en la escritura.

Por tanto, cuando decimos...

> El VPH, según su **sigla**...

usamos la acepción 1ª, que querría decir:

> El VPH, según su abreviación gráfica...

Mientras que cuando decimos...

> El VPH, según sus **siglas**...

usamos la acepción 2ª, que podría extenderse a:

> El VPH, según la combinación de letras Virus de Papiloma Humano...

El Diccionario Panhispánico de Dudas tiene [una entrada](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=nNmc4LzNaD6zHPhgWc) al respecto pero no entra en este tema, sino que incide en lo descrito por el DRAE:

> sigla. 1. Se llama sigla tanto a la palabra formada por las iniciales de los términos que integran una denominación compleja, como a cada una de esas letras iniciales. Las siglas se utilizan para referirse de forma abreviada a organismos, instituciones, empresas, objetos, sistemas, asociaciones, etc.

---

Eso sí, Google Ngram nos indica que *siglas* se usa bastante más que *sigla* (apretad en la imagen para ver el gráfico grande):

[image]

Comment: Mi respuesta no aportaba nada que no tuviera la tuya, que es mucho más completa. Por cierto, ¿has visto [mi nueva medalla](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/badges/37/disciplined)? :D

Comment: @CarlosAlejo jaja ¡bien merecida! Ay, las [Stinking badges](http://agent86ix.github.io/stackapps/badge/) :D